# Make Id column to work with sequence or GenerationType.IDENTITY according to the database

Tags: sql-server, spring, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When we have to use the same code base to work with Oracle or other MSSql databases, is there a way to tell how to choose the type of mapping inside entity classes? For oracle it uses sequences like

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="InvSeq") 
@SequenceGenerator(name="InvSeq",sequenceName="INV_SEQ", allocationSize=5) 
private long id;
```

and for MySQL it uses

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

Is there a way to configure this without duplicating entity classes?

Comment: Which version of Oracle do you use? Starting with 12 you may use `IDENTITY` as well.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber, it's 11 using sequnces

Comment: Why not use sequence for MySQL ?

Comment: @Eklavya-UpvoteDon'tSayThanks no we have clients who use both the dbs

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out. In Spring Boot there is a way we can override default persistence mappings that is there inside a persistence.xml file. We first need to create a bean in app config like this(entityManagerFactory name should be there since spring will look for it):

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(springJpaDataSource());
    factory.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    if(!db_url.contains("oracle"))// something that tells you it's not oracle
    {
        factory.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:jpa/custom-persistance.xml");
    }
    else{
        // this file will not contain any mapping files to override ID generation
        factory.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:jpa/custom-persistance-oracle.xml");
    }
    return factory;
}
```

Now add the file (custom-persistance.xml):

```
<persistence
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit">
    <provider>
        org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    </provider>
    <mapping-file>
        jpa/entity-mappings.xml
    </mapping-file>
</persistence-unit>
```

For custom-persistance-oracle.xml file will be same without mapping-file xml tag. Then add the actual file having mappings:

```
<entity-mappings
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    version="2.1">
<package>com.example.pcakageto.classes</package>
<entity class="ClassA" access="FIELD">
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY"/>
        </id>
    </attributes>
</entity>
<entity class="ClassB" access="FIELD">
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY"/>
        </id>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

Finally ID mappings in Java files should be using sequences as it normally would:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName = "sequence_name", allocationSize=1)
private Integer id;
```